# Retrieving and using user information from parse.com

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform

in my android app I'm putting the location from a currentUser into parse.com's table. I'm having trouble retrieving that information the correct way again.

I want to make a for each loop, for each object, where I use the username and latitude and longitude.

I have read the API for hours, but lists are my weakside and I just can't wrap my head around it.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> users  = ParseQuery.getQuery("user");

ParseObject object = (ParseObject) users.get(user); //This is invald, but dno what to write in "get"

final String objectId = users.getObjectId();
final int olat = users.getInt("lat");
final int olong = users.getInt("lng");
String name = users.getString("username");
```

This information I want to use in a for each loop that then adds a marker of each users last known lat and longitude;

I have this I want to put in the loop;

```
double oldLatitude = olat;
double oldLongitutde = olong;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(oldLatitude, oldLongitutde);
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
   .position(latLng)
  .title(objectId + "was here!");
mMap.addMarker(options);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

I have something like this, but noidea how to handle it;

```
public void handleDiffUsers(Location location){



    users.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
                      //marker code.. ? 
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrive ParseUser list and get `ParseGeoPoint`

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryParseUser = ParseUser.getQuery();
        queryParseUser.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> locationList, ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (locationList != null) {
                        for (ParseUser parseObject : locationList) {
                            ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint = parseObject.getParseGeoPoint("location"); "location" is column name of user table
                            // create marker

                            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                                    new LatLng(parseGeoPoint.getLatitude(), parseGeoPoint.getLongitude())).title(parseObject.getUsername());


                            // Changing marker icon
                            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

                            // adding marker
                            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                        }
                    }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hm, should I use parsequery instead of object? And do I call whereEqualTo for each string/int?

Comment: filter user according to your need like nearest user. see parse.com [docs link](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints)

Comment: Yes ok, Im at a lose.. ("username",username", will not resolve username.. do I need to declare it? And how?

Comment: remove that line. You will get all users.

Comment: It only answers part of my question, I still am not sure how to retrieve the user information and parse it in a for each loop :(

Comment: are you storing `ParseGeoPoint` for `lat` `long` in `User` table ?

Comment: No currently Im just storing the GPS coordinates in my table as lat and lng.. Should I store it as geopoint? and how?

Comment: I have, but really no idea how to apply it correctly.. Currently I have currentUser and put and that way I store latitude n long.. How do I do it with parseGeo?

Comment: post code in which you saving parseUser with lat long

Comment: I have made geopoints work.. Now I just need to retrieve them and add markers for each individual user on the table.. :/

Comment: Awesome! It says username and ic_launcher, cannot resolve.. How do I declare it correctly?

Comment: Thanks! ic_launcher is still unresolvable, should I add it to activitymap.xml somewhere? Sorry Im so new at this :(

Comment: it's location marker image. you can add any image you have. replace code `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)` to `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However I can not get it to display individual markers for each user. I only get the one icon for where I am currently, and I made 4 test users to change login, it does not add geolocation for more than the first user.. and Im a bit confused.. I made a code share with my code; http://codeshare.io/Q49ic

Comment: where you calling `handleDiffUsers` in `activity` ?

Comment: Im not calling that specific method in any activity.xml.. should I ?

Comment: I'm getting a "method is never used" on it actually, but Im unsure how to call it.. I cant make it static, because then my mMap object wont work

Comment: Ive encountered a new error, can you help Kishore?:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772417/geopoints-will-not-parse-in-android-app